# Why am I getting this error "Cannot assign to property: 'blurb' is a get-only property" - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to assign values to a Data Object from a static array in a file called FeaturedData, but I keep getting this annoying error: "Cannot assign to property: 'blurb' is a get-only property"

Here's my Model:

```
struct Featured: Codable {
    var tagline: String
    var title: String
    var blurb: String
}
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class FeaturedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var features = [FeaturedObjectViewModel]()
    var data = FeaturedData()
    
    func setFeatured() {
        for featured in data.featureds {
            let featureObject = FeaturedObjectViewModel(featured: featured)
            featureObject.blurb = featured.blurb
            self.features.append(featureObject)
        }
    }
}

struct FeaturedObjectViewModel {
    let featured: Featured
    
    var tagline: String {
        self.featured.tagline
    }
    
    var title: String {
        self.featured.title
    }
    
    var blurb: String {
        self.featured.blurb
    }
}
```

Here's the line that's prompting the error:

```
featureObject.blurb = featured.blurb
```

I don't get what wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blurb Is a computed property. You can not assign the any values. It’s always returns.

Use init for FeaturedObjectViewModel

```
struct FeaturedObjectViewModel {
    let featured: Featured
    
    var tagline: String = “”
    
    var title: String = “”
    
    var blurb: String = “”

  init(featured: Featured){
      self.featured = featured
      self.tagline = featured.tagline
      self.title = featured.title
      self.blurb = featured.blurb
  }
}
```

Note : By doing this you don’t need to do this,

featureObject.blurb = featured.blurb

It will automatically assign to object value by init.

Also, in your code with computed property, no need to reassign value to featureObject var. When you get it, it will get featured.blurb value.